# jQuery Validation errorPlacement is not working

Tags: jquery, validation

The jQuery Validation `errorPlacement` method is not firing. In fact, the only method that fires is `showErrors`. I think I'm missing something. The code is below.

```
    errorContainer: '#error-messages',
    showErrors: function (errors) {
        $("#error-messages").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: 'Errors',
            buttons: {
                Ok: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    },
    errorLabelContainer: "#error-messages ul",
    wrapper: "li",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.attr('name') == 'a') {      
            error.appendTo($('#restErrorDate'));
        }
    },
    debug: true
```

Comment: The errorContainer and related items were removed to leave the following: Still dont work

Comment: showErrors: function (errors) {
            $("#error-messages").dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: 'Errors',
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            return true;
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.attr('name') == 'a') {      
                error.appendTo($('#restErrorDate'));
            }
        },
        debug: true
    });

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net... can include CDN version of validate plugin to enable it

Answer (score 0):

I believe `errorLabelContainer` will trump `errorPlacement`. The former is intended to display all errors in one place, making the latter redundant and therefore not used.

In your case you are wanting all errors in a `UL` whose parent has `ID=error-messages`

Comment: The errorContainer and related items were removed to leave the following: